# How do I import TestData from csv file into Vugen Script

Tags: csv, vugen

Could some one please guide me how to do this

I would like to import Test Data from the csv file into Vugen Scripts.

Lets say I have Payee.csv file which has 28 columns of Data and csv file located some shared location. In script I need to pass the values from the csv file by importing.How can I do that in Vugen script?

I know in QTP we have DataTable.Import.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

You can import CSV file and use it as a data file for parameterization.

Follow the steps as mentioned below:

1. Select the value you want to parameterize. for an explanation, I took username field (jojo).
2. Right click on the value (jojo) -> select **Replace With Parameter** -> select **Create New Parameter**
   [image]
3. Write P**arameter name** as **username** (any name of your choice) -> select parameter type as **File** -> Click **OK** button.
   [image]
4. Select Yes/No for "Do You want to replace all occurrences" based on your need.
5. The value (jojo) will be replaced as **{Username}**. Username.dat file will be created with only one entry in the file i.e., jojo
6. Right click on **{Username}** -> select **Parameter Properties** -> click **Browse** button under **File Type** -> Select the **CSV** file (Users.csv) you want to import (select Save as type -> All Files (.*) in **Save As** dialogue box).
7. **Parameter Properties** dailougue box shows all the entries in the csv file in tabular format.
8. under **Select Column**, select **By name** radio button -> from dropdown, select "username" (column header) -> click **Close**
   [image]

Repeat the actions for each column in the CSV file, wherever you want to replace the values with data in CSV (column header is the key).

**Second iteration:**

For password parameter, I followed the same process, given the name parameter name as "Password", and selected the same CSV file, under refer the data "By name" -> Password (column header)

Screenshot for Password parameter:
[image]

References:

1. http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/Tutorial/Preparing.htm#How2